# postgis procedure parse error at position 7 within geometry

Tags: geometry, gis, geospatial, postgis, procedure

I can not find the cause of the error in the following SQL code. Please help me!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_points(loc text)
  RETURNS SETOF points_nearby AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
            rec points_nearby;
        points text[];
        j int;
        poi varchar;
        length int;
    BEGIN
        points := string_to_array(loc, ',');
        length := array_length(points, 1);
        j = 1;
        while j <= length 
        LOOP
            poi := trim('SRID=4326;POINT('||points[j]||')');
            FOR rec IN select "gid", "tb_elev" as elevation,
            st_x("geom") as x,
            st_y("geom")as y, 
            st_distance( poi::geometry, "geom" ) as distance 
            from 
                (
                select *
                from
                "tb_elev" 
                where
                st_within("geom" ,st_buffer(poi::geometry, 50) )
                ) as a order by distance limit 4  
            LOOP
                RETURN NEXT rec;
            END LOOP;

            j := j + 1;

        END LOOP;           
        RETURN;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;`



select  get_points('971317 2027702');
```

this is the result messages:

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "971317" <-- parse error at position 7 within geometry
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_points(text) line 15 at FOR over SELECT rows
```

Comment: That's the error for `select  st_x('971317')`. What is the data type for `tb_elev.geom`? Also don't use `st_within("geom" ,st_buffer(poi::geometry, 50) )`; use instead [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html).

Comment: "POSTGIS="2.0.3 r11128" GEOS="3.3.8-CAPI-1.7.8" PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" GDAL="GDAL 1.8.1, released 2011/07/09" LIBXML="2.7.6" LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" TOPOLOGY RASTER"

Comment: above have been installed and tb_elev.geom is geometry(point) column also i try to use st_dwithin function but it's not found